# Text editing in KonvaJS with zoom (scale) applied

Tags: konvajs

I'm trying to implement the complex demo for [text edition](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Editable_Text.html) on the official docs.

It works fine but I have a "zoom" functionality that applies `scale` to the stage and when the `textarea` is created the positioning and size is wrong.

[Example](https://jsbin.com/juwihib/edit?html,js,output)

Is there a workarond to fix this issue?

I know that is something related to stage transform. I'm trying to apply [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615553/issues-when-drawing-using-scale) without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to take `scale` into calculation when you apply styles of `textarea`:

```
textarea.style.width = textNode.width() * textNode.getAbsoluteScale().x + 'px';
```

https://jsbin.com/jufosoqeve/1/edit?html,js,output